# Que veut dire « Le courage c'est tu de prêter flanc aux brises pis aux griffes » ?

Tags: sens, paroles-de-chanson

L’extrait ci-dessous provient de la chanson « Il faut que tu saches » de *Fred Pellerin.* Je ne le comprends pas, donc je vous prie de m’aider à le décortiquer.

> Le courage c'est tu de prêter flanc aux brises pis aux griffes.

Je n’ai pas encadré cette phrase avec des autres morceaux qui sont peut-être liés à celui-ci, car je voulais m’appliquer à la grammaire en laissant de côté le langage figuré dont la chanson est farcie. Cependant, si vous pensez qu’une plus grande partie de la chanson doit être prise en compte, alors je l’ajouterais volontiers.

La suite de mots « c’est tu de » m’étonne, elle ne semble pas être juste, ce qui me fait douter de ce qui la phrase veut dire. Peut-être le chanteur dit :

> Tu serais courageux si te prêtais le flanc aux brises, et aux griffes.

Ou peut-être plutôt

> Le fait que prêtes le flanc aux brises et aux griffes de suite fait
>   preuve de ta vaillance.

Qu’est-ce que vous en pensez ?

Comment: Je ne connais pas la chanson, mais la page [Wikipedia de l'auteur](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fred_Pellerin) indique qu'il est québécois. Et en québécois, c'est assez courant d'ajouter des *tu* après les verbes.

Comment: Autres références : http://youtu.be/en2rTPN37TA?t=1m44s et http://www.parolesmania.com/paroles_fred_pellerin_65660/paroles_il_faut_que_tu_saches_1395005.html

Comment: Et enfin, une explication du *tu* dans les interrogatives en québécois : http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois#Particule_interrogative_.C2.AB_-tu_.C2.BB

Comment: @AlexisPigeon Tu devrais faire une réponse !

Comment: @Laure Pas trop le temps là tout de suite mais je le ferai plus tard dans la soirée. Et entre temps, si toi ou quelqu'un d'autre veut se donner cette peine, pas de problème!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comme l'indique Alexis Pigeon, *-tu* est une particule qui, en français québécois informel, sert souvent à [former des questions](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois#Particule_interrogative_.C2.AB_-tu_.C2.BB). C'est essentiellement la même particule que le *-ti* qui s'emploie d'une manière semblable dans certains dialectes européens.

Ici la phrase se traduit assez directement par

> Est-ce que le courage c'est de prêter flanc aux brises pis aux griffes?

Comment: J'imagine que *pis* veut dire *puis* ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Ici, il veut dire *et*. Quand *pis* veut dire *puis*, il est souvent suivi de *après*, par exemple « on est allés au restaurant pis après au cinéma ».

Comment: Merci d'avoir pris la peine de rédiger une réponse!