# « C'est-y en France — C'est comme en France » ?

Tags: québec, paroles-de-chanson, pronoms-personnels, interrogative, registre

Dans sa chanson *Le Tour de l'Île* (1975), [Félix Leclerc](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A9lix_Leclerc)<sup>2</sup> a écrit :

> Pour célébrer l'indépendance
>  Quand on y pense
> [**C'est-y** en France
>  C'est comme en France](https://youtu.be/Bu8M1fgiFYo?t=5m42s)
>  Le tour de l'île
>  Quarante-deux milles
>  Comme des vagues les
> montagnes
>  Les fruits sont mûrs
>  Dans les vergers
>  De mon
> pays
>
> [ Félix Leclerc, *Le Tour de l'Île* (1975), avant-dernier couplet ]

Ailleurs dans le texte en refrain on trouve *ben* pour *bien*, et ainsi on pensait avoir entendu ici quelque chose comme « *c'est-tu [comme] en France / [que] c'est-tu pas comme en France* », une forme d'alternative sur l'idée d'adéquation, mais non, c'est bien *c'est-y* [sε.ti], et sans les ajouts imaginés ni point d'interrogation. Dans d'autres contenus on a [présenté](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/12143) l'idée de la *particule interrogative*, un élément de syntaxe surtout fonctionnel, et le contenu [*Wikipédia*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois#Particule_interrogative_.C2.AB_-tu_.C2.BB) sur le sujet, où on a l'exemple « *C’est-y pas possible* » ; et donc on comprend qu'il s'agit essentiellement d'une seule et même chose dans tous les cas que ces pseudo-pronoms/particules. C'est entre autres une forme de *notation de la prononciation populaire* ([voir *y*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/y/2) ; aussi, différemment, [y](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/y/1) locatif etc. ; [*il*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ils), réduction latin [*ille*](http://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?q=ille) à *i* ancienne etc.) mais il y a des nuances.<sup>2</sup> La question porte sur l'application de ces concepts et nuances aux deux propositions (en surbrillance dans l'extrait) que je peine à comprendre.

---

- Dans *C'est-y en France*, s'agit-il bien de cette particule/usage particulier et comment exactement (registre ; F. Leclerc prononce-t-il [ti] ou [ty] ; *-y*, variante québécoise ou française ; interrogative ou exclamative ; toute autre information pertinente sur la construction avec *en* qu'on enchaîne sans alternative ni négation), et y a-t-il une raison pour laquelle on utilise *y* plutôt que *ti*, *tu*, *t'i* ou *i* etc. ?
- Quel est donc le *sens exact* qu'exprime l'auteur avec la combinaison *C'est-y en France/C'est comme en France* ; ces deux paroles vont-elles ensemble, et comment ?
- Généralement, au Québec, entend-on *-tu* et *-ti* comme des variantes équivalentes ?

---

<sub>*Notes*</sub>

<sub><sup>1</sup> Pour brièvement situer le poète à son époque et aux lieux, selon l'article Wikipédia, *Félix Leclerc* : 1914, *La Tuque* (Québec) — 1988, *Saint-Pierre-de-l'Île-d'Orléans* (Québec) ; Chevalier de la Légion d'honneur, 1986. Il passe au moins trois ans en France (1950-1953), où il contribuera de manière importante au rayonnement de la chanson québécoise.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> Dans *Le bon usage* (Grevisse et Goosse, *ed. Duculot*, §§395, 659, 1106, 1108, [que cette note paraphrase abondamment]) on traite du sujet sous différents angles, en particulier le « *[ti] dans l'interrogation* » (§395). On dit que de la syllabe *-t-il(s)*, la prononciation populaire [ti], de la même manière que *il* donne [i] dans différents contextes. C'est-à-dire avec une consonne, *il/ils* comme [il]  (soutenu), [i] familier ; devant voyelle [ilz] (soutenu), [iz] (familier), [i] possible au Québec (populaire). Et d'ajouter que quand le pronom suit le verbe, la prononciation [i] est clairement plus familière, et à l'origine du [ti]. On note au passage l'amuïssement représenté graphiquement dans *oui, nenni/o il, nen il* (en effet, de *o je*, *o tu*, *o il*, seul ce dernier demeure ; ce *o*, c'est ce démonstratif latin [*hic/haec/hoc*](http://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?q=hic), *cela*.). Ce ne sont pas des phénomènes récents que ces amuïssements. On dit aussi *c'est-il*, au 15<sup>e</sup>, mais avec un graphie [ti] tellement perçu péjorativement qu'on l'évite même au 18<sup>e</sup> à l'écrit, même dans la bouche de personnages populaires !</sub>

<sub>Ce n'est qu'ensuite qu'on traite de l'usage senti dans différentes régions pour marquer l'interrogative, même avec un verbe à la troisième personne, même avec le pronom *il* précédant ce verbe, et généralement que le sujet soit au masculin ou au féminin (on réfère aux cas du genre : « *il viendra-t-il te voir* » où l'on prononce [i] dans les deux cas). Le *LBU* mentionne que le tour [ti] interrogatif est « *bien vivant* » en Normandie et au Québec ; autrement en recul, malgré l'opinion que certains en avaient :</sub>

> <sub>*C'est le symbole unique de l'interrogation, dont la langue avait
> besoin. On voit avec quelle ingéniosité souple et tenace elle se l'est
> créé.*</sub>
>
> <sub>[Vendryes, *Langage*, 203, présenté au LBU §395]</sub>

<sub>Et c'est là qu'on dit, [ti] au Québec souvent prononcé [ty], c'est-à-dire comme *tu*. On comprend l'utilité d'une fonction qui permette de faire une question ou une variante exclamative utilisant *c'est-ti vrai*, d'une affirmation comme *c'est vrai* (mon opinion). Au *LBU* on conclut sur l'emploi avec *c'est* spécifiquement, pour dire que parfois on a la graphie *c'est-il*, dans le même sens, peut-être sous l'influence de « cela est-il », mais sans aucune idée d'imiter la langue populaire : « *c'est-il mer qui explique qu'amarrer est un verbe « ne se rencontrant que sur le bord de la mer* » ? » (Millardet, *Revue des langues romanes*, 1923). Pour plus d'informations sur le contexte du québécois, nord-américain, voir notes sur *Wikipédia* (par ex. [1](http://www.nou-la.org/ling/1995a-fda.pdf), [2](http://www.nou-la.org/ling/1998a-fpparis.pdf)).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

1) Je crois qu'il s'agit clairement de cet usage oui. Ici le -ty ressort je crois surtout à cause de la référence au pays en question: Félix veut inclure un usage typiquement franco-français.

2) Dans cette optique, la phrase ne peut avoir d'autre sens que "Est-ce [que c'est] en France?". Toute recherche de sens plus approfondie relève clairement non de l'analyse linguistique mais bien de l'analyse littéraire.

3) Au Québec, la formule normale est en -tu. La formule en -ti serait comprise, mais perçue comme étrangère, voire incorrecte si la personne qui l'entend se trouve n'avoir jamais entendu ou lu l'expression chez des Européens.