# C'est-y pas vrai ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, histoire, oral

Dans la lecture du *Voyage au bout de la nuit*, je suis tombé sur cette phrase orale :

> « C'est-y pas vrai ? »

De nos jours, j’emploierais, pour ma part, « C'est pas vrai ? » à la place.

Était-ce à l’époque correct et qu'en est-il aujourd'hui ?

Comment: C'est une façon argotique de dire : "Cela, n'est-il pas vrai, cela ?"

Comment: Personnellement, je n'entend cette expression que de manière ironique, sous entendant que c'est évident.

Comment: @GAVD Votre commentaire peut (doit) être mis en réponse !

Comment: "Cela, n'est-il pas vrai, cela ? En tant que français je ne comprend absolument pas la répétition de cela en fin de phrase. "Ce n'est pas vrai !?" me semble plus juste.

Comment: On retrouve d'ailleurs une tournure similaire en français quebeçois : *C'est-tu pas vrai ?*

Comment: @GAVD et d'ou ca vient ? Puis qui utilise un langage comme celui-la ?

Comment: Il aide de comprendre le [style](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyage_au_bout_de_la_nuit#Style) de l’œuvre et de l'auteur ([Céline](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis-Ferdinand_C%C3%A9line#Le_style_C.C3.A9line)). Voir aussi [ceci](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/16078/3177).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

D'après [le wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/c%E2%80%99est-y_pas), il s’agit plutôt d’une forme familière qu’argotique de « *Cela n’est-il pas vrai ?* ».

Answer (score 0):

Comme l'a dit @GAVD , je pense que c'est une façon familière ou "argotique de dire : *Cela, n'est-il pas vrai, cela ?* "

Comment: Plutôt familière que argotique, le sens est transparent pour tout le monde...

Comment: @GAMPUB s'il etait transparent pour tout le monde, pourquoi aurais-je pose cette question ?

Comment: @oldergod Parce que dans cet espace un grand nombre de questions proviennent de non-francophones. L'argot est spécifiquement une forme de langage qui **vise** à restreindre sa compréhension à une communauté particulière, ce qui ne semble pas être le cas ici.

Comment: @GAMPUB Justement, j'aimerai savoir quelle est cette communaute particuliere―ce n'est deja plus "tout le monde"―pour qui cette expression argotique est transparente. Dans le livre ou je l'ai lu, les caracteres qui l'utilisent proviennet de l'IDF ou j'ai moi-meme vecu 23 ans sans jamais y entendre pareille expression.