# Prononciation du pronom personnel « elle » comme [a] en langue populaire : comment et pourquoi ?

Tags: prononciation, oral, phonétique, pronoms-personnels

> *La môme néant*
>
> Quoi qu'a dit ?
>   — A dit rin.
>   Quoi qu'a fait ?
>   — A fait rin.
>   Quoi qu'a pense ?
>   — A pense à rin.
>
> Pourquoi qu'a dit rin ?
>   Pourquoi qu'a fait rin ?
>   Pourquoi qu'a pense à rin ?
>
> A'xiste pas.
>
> [ [Jean Tardieu](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Tardieu) (1903-1995), *Monsieur, Monsieur* (1951), ed. *Gallimard* ; voir [lecture](http://www.ina.fr/audio/P12052343) de l'auteur ]

Il s'agit de la prononciation ([a]) du pronom personnel féminin *elle* en langue populaire dans diverses régions dont l'auteur se fait l'écho ici. Il peut s'agir d'un [amuïssement](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amu%C3%AFssement) comme on a avec le *l* de *il* (devant consonne *il/ils* comme [il] (soutenu), [i] (familier) ; devant voyelle, au singulier [il] ; au pluriel, [ilz] (soutenu), [iz] (familier) [etc](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/16078). ; voir *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, ed. *Duculot*, 14<sup>e</sup> ed., §659).

---

- Généralement, en France et en Belgique, quelles sont les régions où l'on retrouve le plus ce phénomène touchant le pronom personnel *elle* en langue populaire ?
- Par quelle mécanique [phonétique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phon%C3%A9tique) le pronom *elle* se
  réduit-il parfois à [a] en langue populaire et quelle fonction a cette réduction (pourquoi) ? Est-ce un amuïssement ou un métaplasme, et comment le désigne-t-on précisément ? La variété de français joue-t-elle un rôle important dans ce cas précis ?
- Y a-t-il réduction du même pronom dans une langue plus régulière, et si oui, de quelle manière ? Y a-t-il une nuance à
  faire quand le pronom précède l'auxiliaire *être* ou le verbe *aller*, par exemple ?

Answer (score 2):

Souvent à l'oral, *elle* est réduit en *è* et *il* est réduit en *i* quand ils sont suivis par une consonne.

> *i* fait quoi ?
>
> *è* mange où ?

C'est même tellement souvent qu'entendre quelqu'un prononcer *il fait quoi ?* sonnerait presque littéraire.

Je pense que *a* pour *elle* dérive de la prononciation *è*, assez proche.

Toutefois le texte que tu présentes est clairement un exemple d'accent qu'on qualifierait de *beauf*. Tout y est, de la prononciation de *rien* jusqu'à la syntaxe *pourquoi que ?*. Difficile d'attribuer cet accent à des populations particulières de la France sans tomber dans le cliché ou le dédain, mais il est traditionnellement associé au milieu pauvre, ouvrier, peu éduqué.

Je viens d'une ville normande de pêcheurs, et c'est une façon de parler qu'on y retrouve.

> Vas-y fais-moi montrer comment qu'tu fais.
>
> Où qu't'achètes ton cid', toué ?

Comment: Merci ! On entend ce parler. Le texte de Tardieu est une illustration d'une prononciation du pronom en [a], et ses autres particularités sont sans conséquence sur l'existence de ce genre de prononciation hors du style que vous évoquez, ni ne l'expliquent. On vous invite à aller plus loin. C'est par ailleurs bien intéressant !