# « A » dans les paroles de « Rue Saint-Vincent » d'Aristide Bruant

Tags: paroles-de-chanson, imparfait

Pour décrire la vie d'une jeune fille (Rose), des phrases utilisant un verbe à l'imparfait commencent par des "a".

Par exemple :

> On n'avait pas connu son père
> **A** n'avait plus de mère
> Et depuis 1900
> **A** demeurait chez sa vieille aïeule
> Où qu'a s'élevait comme ça, toute seule
> Rue Saint-Vincent

A quoi sert ce mot dans ses vers ?

Merci beaucoup !

Answer (score 5):

« A’ » est une apocope, variante populaire du pronom féminin *elle* ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/a%E2%80%99#fr)). De plus :

> °[A], prononciation populaire dans diverses régions, pour *elle,
> elles*, plus rarement pour *il, ils*, est parfois relevé par les
> écrivains : *Quoi qu'A dit ? / - A dit rin* ([TARDIEU](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/21638), *Monsieur
> monsieur*, La môme néant). — *A portent des bigoudis [...] parce qu'A
> croient toutes qu'A vont fêter un anniversaire* (R. PlNGET, *Monsieur
> Songe*, p. 60). — *A'* [= les Allemands et les Américains] *sont aussi
> pires eul's uns comme eul's aut'* [dit un Normand] (LE ROY LADURIE,
> *Paris-Montpellier*, p. 22). — *La jeunesse d'asteur sait pas ça. A' regimbe* (A. MAILLET, *Sagouine*, p. 59).
>
> [ *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, éd. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>, § 659 d) 2° ]

Dans cette chanson composée à l'origine par [Aristide Bruant](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristide_Bruant#Par_d%27autres), on veut dire « elle » (*elle n'avait/demeurait/s'élevait* etc.)